# ChromeHeadless not getting started in docker image

Tags: angular, docker, google-chrome-headless

I have an angular 11 project. The ng test is running successfully locally but inside the docker container, I am getting the following error

> ```
> Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
> 14 07 2021 07:20:44.772:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
> 14 07 2021 07:20:44.800:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start ChromeHeadless
>   Can not find the binary /iot-config-tool/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-884014/chrome-linux/chrome
>   Please set env variable CHROME_BIN
> 14 07 2021 07:20:44.800:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stdout: 
> 14 07 2021 07:20:44.800:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stderr: 
> npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
> ```

I am using node:14.17-alpine image. I also tried to install chromium with this command `apk update && apk add --no-cache chromium` but getting the same error.

Here is karma.config.js

Thank you in advance

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();   
    module.exports = function(config) {
      config.set({
        webpack: { node: { fs: 'empty' } },
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
        plugins: [
          require('karma-jasmine'),
          require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
          require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
          require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
          require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
        ],
        client: {
          clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
    
        mime: {
          'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx'],
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
          reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
          fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
        },
        angularCli: {
          environment: 'dev',
        },
        reporters:
          config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
            ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
            : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        singleRun: false,
      });
    };
```

Comment: Can you please add your docker yml as well?

Comment: I am testing it with this command docker run -v `pwd`:/iot-config-tool -it node:14.17-alpine /bin/sh

Answer (score 0):

you want to execute chrome in puppeteer of your node folder
so if your system in 32 bit you can't launch
should you add

```
RUN apk add chromium
RUN apk add chromium-chromedriver
ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

and delete `process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();`
that will be working !